# Как получить количество значений массива с индексом 2 в зависимости от индекса 1

Tags: php, массивы

У меня получился двухмерный массив `$multidim`. В коде ниже я посчитал количество значений равным `$ONI`. Теперь нужно из массива `[индекс2]` получить количество значений, которые соответствуют `$ONI` из `[индекс1]`. Как быть?

Пояснение - `$multidim[индекс1][индекс2]`

```
$ONI="ОНИ";

for ($i=0; $i <$countArray ; $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j <$countArray ; $j++ ){
        if ($multidim[$i][$j]==$ONI) {
            $countAlloni++;
        };
    };
};

echo $countAlloni;


Array 

( [0] => Array 
( [0] => ФПО [1] => ОНИ [2] => ОНИ [3] => ОНИ [4] => ИЭО [5] => ОНИ [6] => ЭП [7] => ЭП [8] => ОСИ [9] => ОСИ [10] => НП [11] => ТКО [12] => ОРГАН [13] => ОДИ [14] => ОДИ [15] => ИЭО ) 

[1] => Array ( [0] => Александр [1] => Ольга [2] => Ольга [3] => Ольга [4] => Ольга [5] => Ольга [6] => Ольга [7] => Ольга [8] => Александр [9] => Александр [10] => Ольга [11] => Ольга [12] => Ольга [13] => Ольга [14] => Ольга [15] => Александр ) )
```

Comment: чего чего надо получить? лучше на примере

Comment: Я не догоняю как посчитать количество элементов в [индексе2] у которых одинаковый [индекс1] и равен $ONI.

Comment: вы бы лучше конкретный пример  массива с цифрами привели

Comment: Обновил, можно так переформулировать - мне нужно посчитать сколько "Александров" относится к "ОНИ"

Comment: дак у вас массив то `2хN` а не `NxN` как вы цикле обходите, где N=countArray ?

Comment: N=countArray посчитано по одному из массивов, а затем я их объединил. Этот цикл для моего массива неправильный?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();

foreach ($multidim[0] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value === $ONI) {
        if (array_key_exists($multidim[1][$key], $result)) {
            $result[$multidim[1][$key]] += 1;
        } else {
            $result[$multidim[1][$key]] = 1;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
array(1) {
   ["Ольга"]=>int(4)
 }
```